# How to write a regex that prevents partial matching

Tags: java, regex, search, partial

How do I build a regex pattern that searches over a text T and tries to find a search string S.

There are 2 requirements:

1. S could be made of any character.
2. S could be anywhere in the string but can't be part of a word.

I know that in order to escape special regex characters I put the search string between \Q and \E as such:

\EMySearch_String\Q

How do I prevent finding partial matching of S in T?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be part of a word"? Does it mean it must be the whole word?  Could you give some positive and negative examples?

Comment: Have you looked at the solution to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java does that help you?

Comment: @vcetinick: `\\b` is no good here, since `S` could include any character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this if
`can't be part of a word`
is interpreted as
`preceded by start-of-string or space and followed by end-of-string or space`:

```
String s = "3894$75\\/^()";
String text = "fdsfsd3894$75\\/^()dasdasd 22348 3894$75\\/^()";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)\\Q" + s + "\\E(?=\\s|$)").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found match! :'" + m.group() + "'");
}
```

This prints only one

> Found match! :'3894$75/^()'

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to find can be easily solved with lookaheads and lookbehinds. [Take a look at this for a good explanation.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Then there's a bit of flip-flopping booleans, but you're looking ahead and behind for NOT Non-Space characters (\S). You don't want to look for space characters only because S might be at the start or end of the string. Like so:

```
(?<!\S)S(?!\S)
```