# Read Certain words from text file java

Tags: java, regex

So i have a text file (`tagged.txt`) full of different sentences. What I am looking to do is read this text file into Java, and extract specific words from this file.

e.g

Sentence : `I went to the shop to buy a new pair of trainers`

If the sentence has the words `shop`, `buy`, or `trainers` in it, I would like that sentence to equal an opinion.

I have created a list of the words in a text file (`words.txt`), in which I would like to stream against the `tagged.txt` file.

I just wanted to know if there is a way of implementing this in Java.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Check the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

- Read the words from `words.txt` and store in an array and sort it using `Arrays.sort(arr)`.
- Read the lines from `tagged.txt` line by line and store it in a `String`. Then you could use `split()` to split the line into different words and store the words in an array.
- Then loop through the words of the line, and use the array's `binarysearch` method to search through the words from the words array.

Comment: Because, only if you sort the words, you can use binary search on the array of words, which is an efficient way to search for words in an array.