# find out the domain from an emailId through regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Suppose the email Id is `abc@xyz.com` and i need to extract the domain name(i.e xyz) from this. 
I'm fully new in regex. By googled a little I find out a possible solution from [this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java) . And tried something like:

```
 if("abc@xyz.com".matches(".*\\xyz\\b.*")){
     //true
 }
```

But it didn't work for me. Is there any solutions for this.

Comment: please add comments for negative vote..so i can findout my mistake..

Comment: Your question does not show any serious research effort and is just asking for the codezzz. Also "what you tried" is just garbage and not related to the question.

Comment: @Theolodis i don't find any cause for negative vote in my question.also i don't say you are wrong. i welcome it.

Comment: I do not say that the question is absolutely stupid, but I wouldn't have asked it because it can be solved by googling 5 minutes.

Comment: @Theolodis I accepted my mistake. i will try to ignore such kind of mistakes in future. And thanks for a nice comment.

Comment: You're welcome, a downvote isn't meant to discourage anyway, it is just to signal to other people that the question could possibly not be very interesting. But you got one of a million possible solutions, so good luck ;)

Comment: I found a more constructive way of showing what I meant: if you would for example have written that you did split the string on the `@`, but you want to know if there is a safer/faster/more intuitive way of achieving that with a regex I wouldn't have concluded that you just want the code. But your code sample is really not related to the context of the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the simplest, you can use this regex:

```
(?<=@)\S+
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/iA7bR0).

- `(?<=@)` is a lookbehind that checks that what precedes is a `@`
- `\S+` matches all chars that are not white-space characters

In Java, you could do this (among several ways to do it):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=@)\\S+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
 ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
    }
```

**Notes**

`\S+` works for the string you presented, but it is a "rough tool" that can match all kinds of characters. If you wanted something more specific, you could replace the `\S+` with this:

```
(?i)\b([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}\b
```

This is an expression from the RegexBuddy library for a domain name. There are thousands of ways of matching a domain name. In your case, if you are sure you are getting an email address, the regex I gave you should work just fine.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.+1 for the testing link..let me try the solution first.

Comment: Thanks a lot.your regex part helped me so much in my logic

Comment: You're very welcome... See you next time, Ranjit! :)