# Find the whole word from a Sentence with matching String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to filter the whole word from the sentence.

like example

**Text : This is a question about programming language.**

**Search Text is : about pro**

**Result should be : about programming**

Basically i want to get the whole words from the sentence.

I referred this [How to find a whole word in a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java) also. but it searching for matching words and not characters

I would really appreciate your help

Thanks

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service. Show us what you have worked out, and where you are stuck,

Comment: @Richard i shared the link what i tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it with regex: Something like

```
about pro.*?\b
```

Will match about pro and then some characters and then a word boundary (a whitespace or punctuation mark). This way you don't have to make multiple substrings (which is a costly operation).