# extracting blocks of information from a text variable in Java

Tags: java

I have a variable text in Java that i managed to read from a calendar blob file. it contain a sample like this:

> "BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Kusss//DE VERSION:2.0 METHOD:PUBLISH
>   BEGIN:VEVENT UID:at-coursedate-1330089 DTSTAMP:20161110T124248Z
>   DTSTART:20161005T114500Z DTEND:20161005T150000Z SUMMARY:Mobile
>   Computing (367008/2016W)\, Lva-LeiterIn: prof DESCRIPTION: LOCATION:S3
>   057 X-GWSHOW-AS:BUSY END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR"

I want to extract specific blocks from the text and store it in an array. my interest is only in getting info of

**DTSTART**:20161005T114500Z
**DTEND**:20161005T150000Z

How can i achieve that with simple JAVA Code?
thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Note that jQuery is nothing to do with Java. I've removed that tag for you

Comment: seems like a date info, since u managed to extract the whole text just extract the DTstart and dtend by regex matcher and pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a whole word in a String in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to delete all backslashes before this works. i would suggest you split the string at every  and the iterate through the array and look if the sting `startsWith(DTSTART)` or `startsWith(DTEND)` if yes you can store them at some place

```
String s=new String("BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Kusss//DE VERSION:2.0 METHOD:PUBLISH BEGIN:VEVENT UID:at-coursedate-1330089 DTSTAMP:20161110T124248Z DTSTART:20161005T114500Z DTEND:20161005T150000Z SUMMARY:Mobile Computing (367008/2016W), Lva-LeiterIn: prof DESCRIPTION: LOCATION:S3 057 X-GWSHOW-AS:BUSY END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR");
    String[] test=s.split(" ");
    for(String str:test){
        if(str.startsWith("DTSTART")||str.startsWith("DTEND")){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

produces:

```
DTSTART:20161005T114500Z
DTEND:20161005T150000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just do:

```
String a = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Kusss//DE VERSION:2.0 METHOD:PUBLISH BEGIN:VEVENT "
         + "UID:at-coursedate-1330089 DTSTAMP:20161110T124248Z DTSTART:20161005T114500Z "
         + "DTEND:20161005T150000Z SUMMARY:Mobile Computing (367008/2016W)\\, Lva-LeiterIn: "
         + "prof DESCRIPTION: LOCATION:S3 057 X-GWSHOW-AS:BUSY END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR";

String start = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("DTSTART"), a.lastIndexOf("DTEND")-1);
String end = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf("DTEND"), a.lastIndexOf("SUMMARY")-1);

System.out.println(start);
System.out.println(end);
```

would produce:

```
DTSTART:20161005T114500Z
DTEND:20161005T150000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pattern regex.

Consider you have your text, and the two keywords, you want to do:

```
String s = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Kusss//DE VERSION:2.0 METHOD:PUBLISH BEGIN:VEVENT UID:at-coursedate-1330089 DTSTAMP:20161110T124248Z DTSTART:20161005T114500Z DTEND:20161005T150000Z SUMMARY:Mobile Computing (367008/2016W)\\, Lva-LeiterIn: prof DESCRIPTION: LOCATION:S3 057 X-GWSHOW-AS:BUSY END:VEVENT END:VCALENDAR";       
findValue(s, "DTSTART");
findValue(s, "DTEND");
```

Send your text, and the desired key to the following method:

```
private static String findValue(String text, String keyword) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(keyword+ ":([^\\s]+)"); // the regex to be found
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) { // if found
        return m.group().replace(dtStartOrEnd + ":", ""); // return found, except 'DTSTART:' / 'DTEND:'
    }
    return null; // Not found
}
```

This method is ready to give you all values within that String, after 'key:' and before the next whitespace.