# how to find particular word from string android

Tags: java, android

i want to check if the particular word is exits or not in the string with ignore case.

My String is - "Hello world , Wassup? , good moRNING".

Now i want to check if the word - "hello world".

so i have tried the following:

```
String fullText = "Hello world , Wassup? , good moRNING";
String singleWord = "hello world";
boolean find;

 if (fullText.matches(singleWord)) {

    find = True;
}
```

I have also tried with `contains` but this is not working.

How can i find this particular word ?

Comment: Try google and look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091057/how-to-find-a-whole-word-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: hello and Hello is different

Comment: Apart from the difference between lowercase and uppercase `h` (as @AdityaVyas-Lakhan pointed out), `contains()` should work. `matches()` is not suited since it (a) requires a regular expression and (b) only returns true if the entire string matches the regex, that is, doesn’t contain more characters before or after.

Comment: It’s an aside: `true` should be with a small `t` (can’t believe how many of the answers copied this error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert both string to common case and then make use of `indexOf` or otherwise with matched you need to make use of a `regex.`

```
String fullText = "Hello world , Wassup? , good moRNING";
String singleWord = "hello world";
boolean find;



if (fullText.toLowerCase().indexOf(singleWord.toLowerCase()) > -1) {

    find = true;
}
```

Comment: Should work (aprat from the capital `T` in `True`). If using Java 5 or newer, `contains()` is simpler.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for pointing it out. I edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
find = fullText.toUpperCase().contains(singleWord.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Worked well for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try lower casing both the sentence to be searched and the string, e.g.

```
if (fullText.toLowerCase().matches(singleWord.toLowerCase())) {
    find = True;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
String string = "Test, I am Adam";
// Anywhere in string
b = string.indexOf("I am") > 0;         // true if contains 

// Anywhere in string
b = string.matches("(?i).*i am.*");     // true if contains but ignore case

// Anywhere in string
b = string.contains("AA")  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the case:

***H***ello world doesn't contains ***h***ello world because it has the capital letter.

Use this:

```
if (fullText.toLowerCase().matches(singleWord.toLowerCase())) {
  find = True;
}
```