# How to check whether element is in the array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

How to check whether element is in the array in java?

```
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a[0] = 5;
        a[1] = 2;
        a[2] = 4;
        a[3] = 12;
        a[4] = 6;
        int k = 2;
        if (k in a) { // whats's wrong here?
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: why are you calling `int[]` a list? Its an array, not a list. List means something else in Java

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "foreach" syntax in java is:

```
for (int k : a) { // the ':' is your 'in'
  if(k == 2){ // you'll have to check for the value explicitly
    System.out.println("Yes");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Paŭlo - Thanks for the edit. I definitely did not notice that 'if' when I copied over his expression.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the search yourself. If the list were sorted, you could use `java.util.arrays#binarySearch` to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If using java 1.5+

```
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Object>(); //build list 

for ( Integer i : l1 ) {  // java foreach operator 
  if ( i == test_value ) { 
      return true; 
  } 
} 
return false;
```

Comment: 1) Can't have primitives in a list. 2) It's List, not list. 3) You can't instantiate a List because it's an interface not a class.

Comment: You would probably want List<Integer> in this case.  Downvote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong? The compiler should say you that there is no `in` keyword.

Normally you would use a loop here for searching. If you have many such checks for the same list, sort it and use binary search (using the methods in `java.util.Arrays`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking array you can use ArrayList. You can do the following

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(5);
list.add(2);
list.add(4);
list.add(12);
list.add(6);
int k = 2;
if (list.contains(k) { 
    System.out.println("Yes");
}
else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the array comparing each element until you find the one that you are looking for:

```
// assuming array a that you defined.
int k = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    if(k == a[i])
    {
        System.out.println("Yes");
        break;
    }
}
```