# Sorting Strings and extracting common elements of two String arrays in Java

Tags: java, string, sorting, comparison

I was asked to write down a Java function `sharedStr` that by given 2 sorted arrays of `String`s, returns the number of `String`s that appear in both of the arrays.

The solution for this code must be linear, which means that I must go through each array only once. Otherwise, I could just compare each `String` in the first array to all the `String`s in the other array.

For example the following call to `sharedStr`

```java
sharedStr({"Call","me","Ishmael"},{"Call","me","Jonha"});
```

must return `2`. I would like your help to understand what does it mean *sorted arrays that contain* `String`*s*? There isn't any special description of the way the arrays have been sorted. What is the basic ordinary sorting of `String`s?

How does one compare between two `String`s anyway? If I try to do so, I get a compiler error. (I'm using Eclipse. I noticed that `char`s can be compared automatically).

Comment: I don't know:
heres the only examples:

sharedStr({"Call","me","Ishmael"},{"Call","me","Jonha"})  2
sharedStr ({"a","c","x"},{"z","b","c","x","a"})  3
sharedStr ({"a","b","c"},{"a","b","c"})  3

Comment: If the assumption was, "given two sorted arrays of strings," does it really matter how the sort came to be? Was the question about an algorithm given this assumption, or does it require the sorting itself in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, second example is for un-sorted code, first I wanted to understand what does it mean, before I write the un-sorted one.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible without comparing each element to each element unless they are sorted.

Comment: @user: well I was asked for linear solution for both cases.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in the two arrays? Ie, is {"a", "b", "b", "c", "d"} a valid input? It is sorted strictly speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x =  0;
int i= 0;
int j = 0;
while(i != list1.length && j != list2.length){
  int v = list1[i].compareTo(list2[j]);
  if (v == 0){
    x++;i++;j++;
  }else if (v < 0){
    i++;
  } else {
    j++;
  }
}
return x;
```

This makes the straightforward assumption that the strings are sorted using String.compareTo which would make sense.

Comment: I edited it to terminate the while loop, oops.
Also, this won't work in case of duplicates, but that can easily be remedied in the v==0 section if needed

Comment: By the way, Someone noted that for an un-sorted arrays, there is no linear implementation. Is it right? should I give up before starting?

Comment: I don't think you could do it in O(n) for unsorted lists, you certainly could in O(nlog n) by sorting then using this.

Comment: @Nir: Correct - there is no linear implementation. Try to work out an example using randomized arrays and see what it would take - it should be fairly self evident.

Answer (score 4):

> What does it mean sorted arrays that contains strings? There isn't any special description of the way it has been sorted. what is the basic ordinary sorting of strings?

It means the elements in the array are ordered in a natural sequence. For strings this is alphebetical order with lowercase words place before upper case.

> How does one compare between two strings any way?

By invoking the `compareTo` method. If it returns 0 they strings are equal, if return  <  0 the first string is lower than the second, if return > 0 the firs string is higher than the second.

As for how to count repetitions linearly see this: [comparing strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505981/comparing-strings-in-java/5506063#5506063)

Answer (score 2):

1. Strings are usually ordered in lexicographic fashion (alphabetical). However, as long as the ordering is consistent, the exact ordering method is not important for this problem (they could be reverse sorted for instance).
2. Java compares objects (not object references) using `.equals()` (for boolean) or `.compareTo()` (for relational comparison) For instance:

.

```
String a = "Hello";
a.equals("Hello"); // true
String b = "Not hi";
b.equals(a); // false
```

Be careful accidentally using  `==` - for constant strings, due to VM designs, it may actually say two Strings are equal, as they are in fact the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing was specified on what the ordering means, then it's probably indicative that it is the natural ordering of Strings which is lexicographic - [from the JavaDoc for the appropriate function to compare two Strings - `compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), the definition of lexicographic ordering is copied and pasted below.

Note that using `compareTo()` is different from simply checking the *equality* of two strings which is done using the [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method (and not the `==` operator which doesn't doesn't check for '*meaningful*' equality, only referential equality); `compareTo` on the other hand will tell you what the relative ordering between two strings is i.e. are they equal (return value of 0) or does one come before the other?):

> This is the definition of
>   lexicographic ordering. If two strings
>   are different, then either they have
>   different characters at some index
>   that is a valid index for both
>   strings, or their lengths are
>   different, or both. If they have
>   different characters at one or more
>   index positions, let k be the smallest
>   such index; then the string whose
>   character at position k has the
>   smaller value, as determined by using
>   the < operator, lexicographically
>   precedes the other string. In this
>   case, compareTo returns the difference
>   of the two character values at
>   position k in the two string -- that
>   is, the value:
>
> ```
>  this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)
> ```
>
> If there is no index position at which
>   they differ, then the shorter string
>   lexicographically precedes the longer
>   string. In this case, compareTo
>   returns the difference of the lengths
>   of the strings -- that is, the value:
>
> ```
>  this.length()-anotherString.length()
> ```

This effectively means they're ordered alphabetically with shorter strings in lower case first, just like in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

First, the second part of your question:

Comparing strings in Java isn't as simple as:

```
if(sStringOne == sStringTwo)
    //Equal
```

you should instead use methods of the string class

```
if(sStringOne.equals(sStringTwo)
    // Equal
```

Second, the first part of your question:

Yes, it would be easy to loop through the first array and count each indexs occurence in the second array. Since you've specified each array must be iterated only once however, perhaps the following algorithm may suit:

1. Create an integer variable initialised to zero to count the matching occurences.
2. Loop through array one
   2.1 For each index, check to see if it's string is present in the other array, do this with the contains function [contains function example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)
   2.2 If string is found in other array, increment counter.
3. read the counter, this is the number of matching strings

Answer (score 1):

Go with the assumption that the two lists are sorted before entering your `sharedStr` algorithm. You'd want to keep two references: each to an element in each of the two lists.

Then you'd start comparing element after element and progress either or both of the references accordingly. Here's a pseudo-code:

```
def sharedStr(lista, listb):
    indexa = indexb = 0
    shared = 0

    while 1:
        try:
            a = lista[indexa]
            b = listb[indexb]
        except IndexError:     # we fell off one of the lists
            break

        if a == b:
            shared += 1
            indexa += 1
            indexb += 1
        elif a < b:
            indexa += 1
        else:    # b < a
            indexb += 1

    return shared
```

Yes, this is also a valid Python code. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because the arrays are sorted, you can step through them knowing you're walking them in order.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
class StringTest {
    static List<String> sharedStrings(String[] a, String[] b) {
        List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
        int apos = 0;
        int bpos = 0;
        while(!(apos == a.length || bpos == b.length)) {
            int comp = a[apos].compareTo(b[bpos]);
            if(comp == 0) result.add(a[apos++]);
            else if(comp > 0) bpos++;
            else apos++;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[]{"this","is","a","test"};
        String[] b = new String[]{"test","for","a","party"};

        java.util.Arrays.sort(a);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(b);

        List<String> result = sharedStrings(a,b);
        for(String s : result) System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the arrays are sorted is a red herring, it is irrelevant to the solution. 
Use a Map<String, Integer>
Steps:

1. For each string in the first array do the following:

   1. do a map.get(currentString)
   2. if that is null, do a map.put(currentString, new Integer(0))
2. For each string in the second array do the following:

   1. do a map.get(currentString)
   2. if that is null, ignore it, it is not a duplicate.
   3. If that is not null, do a map.put(currentString, new Integer(currentInteger.intValue() + 1);
3. do a map.getKeySet().iterator() and iterate through the keys.
4. for each key, get the value.  The value is the count of strings that are in both arrays.