# calling StringArray in if Statement for check the item name is correct

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner for Android, im having stringArray resource on string.xml file.. i need check whether the item name is correct then i hav to do something.. im entering the correct item name but it goes to else part.. may be the problem is in if(itemname=stringArray).. plz give me the solution ..

```
String[]  drugs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Drugsinfo);

if(editext1.getText().equals(drugs))        

{

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some usefull info for you buddy ...",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Descriptionjava.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
}

else 

{
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong pill name !! check out the list",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 bt1.setEnabled(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, how to compare Strings with String Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936141/java-how-to-compare-strings-with-string-arrays)

Comment: O(N) solution is to iterate the array and check if current item is equal to given string ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };

        if (Arrays.asList(bob).contains("silly")) {
            // true
        }
```

"silly" is text of your EditText.

For getting text from edit text and compare according to your comment use some like:

```
if(yourEditText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("silly"))
{
//do your work here
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: how can i get item info from String Array Resources ??

Comment: im having all item names in StringArray resource.. either we can use String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" }; like this... if am entering one item name in edittext box i should get the exact item name ..                                                                                                       String[] bob = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" }; 
    
  if(et1.getText().toString().equals(Arrays.asList(bob).contains("silly"))) {
                    // true
       }  equals() between objects of inconvertible types 'string' and 'editable' .

Comment: You can get String Array Resources as:                                  String[] bob=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bob);

Comment: that only i earlier !!   : String[]  drugs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Drugsinfo);

Comment: still am having problem in FOR statement ...getting yellow mark on FOR statement - for loop replacable with foreach

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test it but you could try this.

```
String[]  drugs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Drugsinfo);

for(int index = 0; index < drugs.length;index++) {
   if(editext1.getText().toString().equals(drugs[index])) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some usefull info for you  buddy        ...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Descriptionjava.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
} else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong pill name !! check out the       list",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   bt1.setEnabled(true);    
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this !! getting yellow mark on equals() and FOR .....(i) equals() between objects of inconvertible types 'string' and 'editable' ..  (ii)   for loop replacable with foreach....

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the "toString()" part. I've edited the code

Comment: still am having problem in FOR statement ...getting yellow mark on  FOR statement - for loop replacable with foreach.