# How can I verify that an array of strings contain a certain string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare

Given :

```
String[] directions = {"UP","DOWN","RIGHT","LEFT","up","down","right","left"};

String input = "Up";
```

How can I verify that an input from `stdin` is within the `directions` array or not ?

I can make a loop and check each item with `input` using equal ,but I'm looking for a more elegant way.

Regards,Ron

Comment: Did you search stackoverflow before posting the question?

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Convert the array of valid directions to a list:

```
List valid = Arrays.asList(directions)
```

Or just declare it directly as:

```
List valid = Arrays.asList("UP", "DOWN", "RIGHT", "LEFT", "up", "down", "right", "left")
```

You can then use the `contains` method:

```
if (valid.contains(input)) {
    // is valid
} else {
    // not valid
}
```

Note that this won't match a mixed case input such as "Up" so you might want to store just the uppercase values in the list and then use `valid.contains(input.toUpperCase())`

Comment: I'd prefer foreach on array, over creating new List just to iterate on it...

Comment: Question for everybody - anybody have any idea why Java doesn't have an Arrays.indexOf() method?  (to parallel List.indexOf()).  Since the array of Strings is usually some static final thing, I find the converting to a List very annoying, so I usually write my own little linear search utility.

Comment: @user949300 - use ArrayList()

Comment: Mostly because generics and arrays don't get along.  Avoid using arrays, use `List`.

Comment: Does not work. I created a 2D array in which every element is "EMPTY". `Arrays.asList(array).contains("EMPTY")` returns true until one element changes to something that isn't "EMPTY". Why? The array still contains "EMPTY".

Comment: @ErikHumphrey if it's a 2D array then does it contain an array that contains "EMPTY" rather than just "EMPTY" itself? If you're still having trouble then post a fresh question with an example of your code.

Comment: @mikej What do you mean? Every element in all of the arrays is a string "EMPTY".

Comment: If you have an array of arrays and use `asList` then you'll get a `List` of arrays, so a `contains` check for a string won't match. Anyway, sounds like your scenario is different to the original question here. If you need a hand, post a fresh question with code demonstrating the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user949300 Java has a `Arrays.binarySearch`, but while this expects the array to be sorted, it is far quicker with larger array sizes

Answer (score 6):

Convert your array to a List and than use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
List mylist = Arrays.asList(directions);
mylist.contains(input);
```

The contains method returns:

> true if the list contains the specified element.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ArrayList` instead and its `contains` method

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Java does not have an `Arrays.indexOf()` method.  Your best bet is to write a little utility to do a simple linear search.  Or you could convert to an ArrayList (see `Arrays.asList()`) and call `indexOf() or contains()`.

If the array is large and speed is a concern, you could sort the array, and then use `Arrays.binarySearch().`

Answer (score 0):

Since we are specifically talking about arrays of strings, not just any array: another approach which solves the case-insensitivity question elegantly would be using regular expressions. Either through the [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class or the String's [matches method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-).

```
if (input.matches("(?i)" + String.join("|", directions))) {
    // valid
}
else {
    // invalid
}
```