# Java - Check if item is in array

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

I have an array setup as follows:

```
Material[] blockedlevel1 = {
            Material.mymaterialone, Material.mymaterialtwo  
        };
```

How do I see if a Material is in this array?

Comment: Look for it, I'd think.  There's that "do loop" thingie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about looking for it in the array?

```
for (Material m : blockedlevel1) {
    if (m.equals(searchedMaterial)) { // assuming that equals() was overriden
        // found it! do something with it
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I set what "m" is so that I can compare it to the array? I need to check `Material block = event.getBlock().getType();` (that is my material).

Comment: In the above loop, `m` gets bound to each of the array's elements in turn; you don't need to _set_ it, the `for` loop does it for you. What you need to take care of, is to provide a `searchedMaterial` against which you can compare (it'd be `block` in your example), to implement an `equals()` method in the `Material` class, and to do something inside the `if`, once you find the material.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an easy way to check if an element is part of a collection you should probably consider a different data-structure like Set (and use contains()). With  Array you can only iterate over the elements and compare each one.

Answer (score 1):

How about looking for it using the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class?

See [Arrays#binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Or as someone suggested, turn your array into a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and use the [contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method. Remember that you *may* have to override the Material#equals method.