# Java arraylist cannot find constructor, using arrays.aslist

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist

I'm using the Arrays.asList().contains() method in my code, as shown in the top answer: [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value), so I am going to use Arrays.asList() in the code.

However, the compiler rejects this following code. Is it because of using primitives for my primes array, rather than a reference type? I don't think so, due to autoboxing, but I just wanted to check.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class .... {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] primes = formPrimes(15);
        ArrayList<Integer> primes1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(primes));
        // Rest of code...
    }

    public static int[] formPrimes(int n) {
        // Code that returns an array of integers
    }
}
```

I get one error, a cannot find symbol error.

symbol  : constructor ArrayList(java.util.List)

location: class java.util.ArrayList
        ArrayList primes1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(primes));

Basically, I've got a function returning an array of integers, and I want to convert it into an array list, and I'm running into trouble with using the ArrayList constructor.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking it may be because Arrays.asList returns a list, not an array list. Would that be it?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be it--both an ArrayList and a List are a Collection, which is what the ArrayList ctor expects. It's because you're mixing types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Autoboxing does not apply to arrays, only to primitives.

The error I get in eclipse is 
`The constructor ArrayList<Integer>(List<int[]>) is undefined`

Thats because the constructor in ArrayList is defined as `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`. As you can see, it only accepts a subtype of Collection, which int is not.

Just change your code to:

```
public class .... {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] primes = formPrimes(15);
        ArrayList<Integer> primes1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(primes));
        // Rest of code...
    }

    public static Integer[] formPrimes(int n) {
        // Code that returns an array of integers
    }
}
```

and all should be well, assuming you return an Integer array from `fromPrimes`.

**Update**
From Andrew's comments, and after peeking into the source of Arrays.asList:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

So what is really happening here is that `Arrays.asList(new int[] {})` would actually return a `List<int[]>`, unlike `Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {})` which would return a`List<Integer>`. Obviously the ArrayList constructor will not accept a `List<int[]>`, and hence the compiler complains.

Comment: I think the problem lies more in the fact that you don't want to have a list of arrays, rather a list of items in the array.

Comment: Andrew, this also explains why a similar code of mine using Arrays.asList() worked for string arrays, since strings are clearly a valid generic type. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`primes` is an array of the primitive `int` type; that type does not derive from `Object` and can therefore be automatically placed into a `List` (which, like all `Collections`, can only hold `Object`s).  @Justin is right; you need to manually add the items from your array to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this to get access to the contains
 method you may as well write your own.

```
public boolean contains(int[] array, int item) {
  for (int element: array)
    if (element == item)
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's another alternative. I was trying to get access to the contains method, and I guess I didn't really think of this.