# Making sure that all elements in array is not zero

Tags: java, arrays

How can I code this in a simpler way?

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] == 0)
    {
        myBoolean = false;
        break;
    }
    else if(myArray[0] != 0 && myArray[1] != 0 && myArray[2] != 0)
    //may continue depending on array length
    {
        myBoolean = true;
    }
}
```

What I currently have is a "if else statement" that if in my array, just an element is not zero it will change my boolean to true. But what I need is to make sure that all elements in the array is not zero then it will change the boolean to true.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Answer (score 5):

You're overcomplicating it: :-) *(I seem to have misread the question earlier, but I've fixed the answer now.)*

```
boolean allNonZero = true;
for (int i = 0; allNonZero && i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        allNonZero = false;
    }
}
```

or even

```
boolean allNonZero = true;
for (int i = 0; allNonZero && i < array.length; ++i) {
    allNonZero = array[i] == 0;
}
```

or using the enhanced for loop:

```
boolean allNonZero = true;
for (int entry : array) {
    if (entry == 0) {
        allNonZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

```
boolean isAllNonZero = true;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i] == 0) {
        isAllNonZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check pretense of zero.

```
boolean isAllNonZero = true;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] == 0)
    {
        isAllNonZero = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(!isAllNonZero) {
  System.out.println("Array Contains zero value");
}
```

Even more

```
int count = 0 ;
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    if(myArray[i] == 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
if(count>0){
  System.out.println("Array Contains "+count+" zeros");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is (I think) the briefest way to do it:

```
boolean allNonZero = true;
for (int i : array)
    if (!(allNonZero &= i != 0)) break;
```