# Is there an "in" Python keyword equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, python

What is the most simple/efficient way of implementing the following Python code in Java?

```
if "foo" in ["foo", "bar"]:
    print "found."
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have your data in array use this

```
String[] strings = {"foo","bar"};
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (s.equals("foo")) {
            System.out.println("found");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the best answer. For better ones, see [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1128723/1097104)