# How can I see if part of a word is contained in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

For instance, let's say I have the following array of app names:

```
{"Math Workshop", "Math Place", "Mathematics", "Angry Birds"}
```

I want to scan this array for any elements that contains the word `math`. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a loop & regular expressions!

Comment: Hmmm... what have you tried so far ?

Comment: `yourString.contains("Math");`

Comment: @TroyAndAbed He might want to do a `.toLowerCase()` first.

Comment: Maybe this question can help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: @user2062810 That would help if the OP was seeking whole words, not partial words.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed. Yes, it's a simple question and yes some prior research should have happened. But I can easily imagine other people seeking an answer to this problem. I'm voting to re-open. At the very worst, it should be closed as a duplicate if anyone kind find one.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
String[] appNames = {"Math Workshop", "Math Place", "Mathematics", 
    "Angry Birds"};

for (String name: appNames) {
  if (name.toLowerCase().contains("math")) {
    // TADA!!!
  }
}
```

Since `contains()` is case-sensitive, you will need to convert your string to lower case if you want a case-insensitive match.

Comment: And it isn't a bad idea to pass the `Locale` to `toLowerCase()`, too

Answer (score 2):

```
for (String title : array) {
    if (title.toLowerCase().indexOf("math") != -1). {
        return true;
    } 
}
return false;
```