# In Java, how can I determine if a char array contains a particular character?

Tags: java, arrays

Here's what I have:

```
char[] charArray = new char[] {'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

I want to write something to the effect of:

```
if(!charArray contains 'q'){
     break;
}
```

I realize that .contains() can't be used here. I am just using "contains" to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: @Aaron: No, you can't use `Arrays.asList()` for **primitive** arrays.

Answer (score 36):

The following snippets test for the "not contains" condition, as exemplified in the sample pseudocode in the question. For a direct solution with explicit looping, do this:

```
boolean contains = false;
for (char c : charArray) {
    if (c == 'q') {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!contains) {
    // do something
}
```

Another alternative, using the fact that `String` provides a `contains()` method:

```
if (!(new String(charArray).contains("q"))) {
    // do something
}
```

Yet another option, this time using `indexOf()`:

```
if (new String(charArray).indexOf('q') == -1) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The logic seems backwards; OP wants to break when the character is _not_ in the character array. Not a biggie for alternatives 2 and 3 (just reverse the sense of the tests), but option 1 would need a little make-over.

Comment: @TedHopp agreed, edited to reflect OP's sample pseudocode. The question is confusing, the title asks how to determine "if a char array contains a particular character", but the sample code implies a "not contains" situation

Answer (score 7):

This method does the trick.

```
boolean contains(char c, char[] array) {
    for (char x : array) {
        if (x == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Example of usage:

```
class Main {

    static boolean contains(char c, char[] array) {
        for (char x : array) {
            if (x == c) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        char[] charArray = new char[] {'h','e','l','l','o'};
        if (!contains('q', charArray)) {
            // Do something...
            System.out.println("Hello world!");
        }
    }

}
```

---

Alternative way:

```
if (!String.valueOf(charArray).contains("q")) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: You should not be using `_` as a variable name even as an example.

Comment: Also, you probably should just coalesce your multiple answers into one, as @ÓscarLópez did.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate through the array or you can convert it to a `String` and use `indexOf`.

```
if (new String(charArray).indexOf('q') < 0) {
    break;
}
```

Creating a new `String` is a bit wasteful, but it's probably the tersest code. You can also write a method to imitate the effect without incurring the overhead.

Comment: He has used falsy condition.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - No, I think I mean `< 0`. OP wants to break if the character is _not_ in the character array.

Comment: @mikeyaworski - No. If `q` is not in the string, then `indexOf` will return -1, which is when OP wants to break. Look at OP's question; there's a `!` operator in front of the test.

Answer (score 4):

Some other options if you do not want your own "Utils"-class:

Use Apache commons lang ([ArrayUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html)):

```
@Test
public void arrayCommonLang(){
    char[] test = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    Assert.assertTrue(ArrayUtils.contains(test, 'o'));
    Assert.assertFalse(ArrayUtils.contains(test, 'p'));
}
```

Or use the builtin [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
@Test
public void arrayTest(){
    char[] test = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    Arrays.sort(test);
    Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.binarySearch(test, 'o') >= 0);
    Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.binarySearch(test, 'p') < 0);
}
```

Or use the [Chars](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html) class from Google Guava:

```
@Test
public void testGuava(){
    char[] test = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    Assert.assertTrue(Chars.contains(test, 'o'));
    Assert.assertFalse(Chars.contains(test, 'p'));
}
```

Slightly off-topic, the Chars class allows to find a subarray in an array.

Comment: `binarySearch` when the array is not sorted returns an undefined result (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(char[],%20char))

Comment: CAUTION: The array must be sorted (as by the sort(char[]) method) prior to making Arrays.binarySearch() call.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation of Oscar's first version that doesn't use a for-each loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    if (charArray[i] == 'q') {
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
```

You could have a boolean variable that gets set to false before the loop, then make "do something" set the variable to true, which you could test for after the loop. The loop could also be wrapped in a function call then just use 'return true' instead of the break, and add a 'return false' statement after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

From [NumberKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/NumberKeyListener.html) source [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/4df2423a947bcd3f024cc3d3a1a315a8dc428598/core/java/android/text/method/NumberKeyListener.java#81). This method they use to check if char is contained in defined array of accepted characters:

```
protected static boolean ok(char[] accept, char c) {
    for (int i = accept.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (accept[i] == c) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It is similar to @ÓscarLópez solution. Might be a bit faster cause of absence of foreach iterator.

Answer (score -1):

You can also define these chars as list of string. Then you can check if the characters is valid for accepted characters with list.Contains(x) method.