# check whether string contains any of the given charsequence

Tags: java

I have got a String array and I want to check various subsections of the array whether they contain *any* and not *all* of the given characters in the CharSequence

For example

```
CharSequence obj = "12";
//convert section to string
String s = Arrays.asList(arr[1]).subList(0,2).toString();
if (s.contains(obj))
{
    System.out.print("yes");
}
```

This prints out `yes` only when both 1 and 2 are to be found in `s` but I want to check whether either 1 or 2 are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your chars in a regex:

```
CharSequence obj = "12";
String s = Arrays.asList(arr[1]).subList(0,2).toString();
if (s.matches(".*[" + obj + "].*")) {
    // either "1" or "2" is in s
}
```

FYI, in java `matches()` must match the *whole* string to return `true` - that's why the `.*` is on either end of the regex.

Comment: Be aware this is slow due to the parsing required in the regex. In cases where performance matters you want to use indexOf.

Comment: @javadba the "performance probkem" would be negligible (a few micro seconds).  Simple, readable, brief code is preferable to verbose, complicated but fast code, unless you actually can prove there's a performance problem that needs fixing

Comment: @Bohemian  Suit yourself - earlier this year I reduced the runtime of a critical high volume app by 75% just by being more careful with string manipulation items and the first thing that had to go were the split()'s, Pattern's etc anything that required a formal parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence obj = "12";
      //convert section to string
      String s = Arrays.asList(arr[1]).subList(0,2).toString();

    for(int i = 0;i<obj.lenth();i++){
      if (s.indexof(obj.charAt(i)) != -1)
        {
            System.out.print("yes");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is clear. I want to avoid the loop obviously but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to your problem is similar as to what was asked here: [In Java, how can I determine if a char array contains a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581531/in-java-how-can-i-determine-if-a-char-array-contains-a-particular-character)

That question had a few interesting solutions offered: 1) you can use indexOf, or 2) you can test for the conditions in which what you're looking for ISN'T in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the method **containsAny** shown below.

```
public class InTest {   
    public static boolean containsAny(String strToSearch, CharSequence chars) {
        for (int i=0;i<chars.length(); i++) {
            if (strToSearch.indexOf(chars.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(containsAny(args[0],args[1]));
    }
}
```

Try it out:

```
C:\apps\simpleakka>javac InTest.java

C:\apps\simpleakka>java InTest "abcdefghij" "i"
true

C:\apps\simpleakka>java InTest "abcdefghij" "n"
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0, i < obj.length() && !found; i++)
{
    if(s.contains(obj.subSequence(i, i + 1)))
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
if(found)
{
    System.out.print("yes");
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, yeah I can do it but I ll have to to loop and check many times so I want to avoid the loop.