# Incompatible operand types char and Class

Tags: java

I'm  working on a mini wheel of fortune game, and I'm trying to restrict the use of a vowel, since they did not buy it.

What I'm not understanding is the if loop at the end. it says that it is incompatible with the operand types, but I'm not sure why. Am I doing something wrong?

```
char[] cons= {'B','C','D','F','G','H','J','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
switch (input) {
            case Guess:             
                System.out.println("The wheel lands on $" + spins);
                System.out.println("Guess a consonant");
                char letter = kb.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0); 
                if (letter == cons[]) {
                   //allow usage of letter
                }
}
```

Comment: How is `input` and `Guess` defined? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The issue is that you are trying are using the '==' operator with 2 different types. 'letter' is a char, while 'cons' is an array of char.

Comment: Make `cons` a `String`, then use `indexOf()` to test if it contains the character: `String cons = "BCDFGHJ..."; if (cons.indexOf(letter) >= 0) { ... `

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to make sure the letter is contained inside the `cons` array. You can't use the `==` operator like that because you are trying to compare a `char` with a `char[]`. You'll want to do some sort of `contains` check.

This answer has some pretty good options:
[In Java, how can I determine if a char array contains a particular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581531/in-java-how-can-i-determine-if-a-char-array-contains-a-particular-character)