# How to check the presence of a string in my string array.?

Tags: java, android

I have a string array. Now I prompt the user for a string and then I need to check if that string is present in the string array or not. Someone please help me do this.

Comment: Please spend a minute reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please share what you have tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: @Atul Dhanuka Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

```
 if(check(edittext.getText.toString())){
//do somethingif true
}else{
//else
}

public boolean check(String text){
for(String s: text){
if(s.equalsIngoreCase(text)){
return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] ordinals = {"donut", "eclair", "froyo", "gingerbread"};
String mystr="donut";
  for (String ord : ordinals) {
     if (mystr.contains(ord)) {
         System.out.println(mystr);
        break;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String[] ar = {"abc","xyz","pqr"};//Input array
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    String key = "abc";//Your key
    if(Arrays.binarySearch(ar, key) >= 0) {
        return true;//Key found
    }
```

It is useful if array size is big