# Does Java have an "in" or "not in" operator similar to Python?

Tags: java, python, operators

I'm working on a project in Java and I wanted to know if Java had a similar "in"/"not in" operator in Python like the example below.

```
>>>"jim" in "jimbo"
>>>True
```

Comment: `contains()` should be what you are looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: The Python the `in` operator maps to the object's `__contains__()` method. I believe Java string objects have something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For strings there is:

```
"jimbo".contains("jim"); // true
```

Check the documentation for `String`. There is also `startsWith`, `endsWith` and `matches` (which uses regular expressions).

Comment: contains is a very handy method found on other types as well

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You should do

```
"jimbo".contains("jim")
```