# Using values of String array for using in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement

In this case, if the user enters any one of the values available in the array `fruits`, I want the `if` statement to come `true`, however I don't understand how to accomplish that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Strings {

public static void main(String[] args) {


Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] fruits = {"Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "Orange", "orange"};

System.out.println("Enter a name of a fruit: ");
String input = Scan.nextLine();
if(/*input = any one of the values in Array fruits*/){
    System.out.println("Yes, that's a fruit");
        }
else{
    System.out.println("No, that's not a fruit.");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, how can I test if an Array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/in-java-how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: Arrays.asList(fruits).contains(input) will work for you :)

Comment: You need a loop to traverse in the array searching for user input if it matches

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it to work using Arrays.asList(fruits).contains(input) as Parth suggested. I have no idea how it works, since I've just started learning Java, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to convert the array to a `List` an use the `contains` method:

```
List<String> fruits =
    Arrays.asList("Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "Orange", "orange");

System.out.println("Enter a name of a fruit: ");
String input = Scan.nextLine();
if(fruits.contains(input) {
    System.out.println("Yes, that's a fruit");
        }
else{
    System.out.println("No, that's not a fruit.");
}
```

However, this will probably have pretty lousy performance. Converting it to a `HashSet` should take care of that:

```
Set<String> fruits = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Apple", "apple", "Banana", "banana", "Orange", "orange"));
// rest of the code unchanged
```