# Is it possible to print a number ONLY if it is a value in an array? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to print out an int ONLY if it is a value in an array of numbers. 
For example:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class arrays {
    Random random = new Random();

    public void method () {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        int j = random.nextInt(20);

        if() {
            System.out.println("It is in the array.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not in the array.");
        }
    }
}
```

What I am not sure about is what you would put in the parentheses after the "if" in order for the System to print "It is in the array" ONLY if j is between 1 and 9.

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible to see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1128728/3651739

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class arrays {
    Random random = new Random();

    public void method () {
        Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        int j = random.nextInt(20);

        if(Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(j)) {
            System.out.println("It is in the array.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not in the array.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but no matter what number j is (I added "System.out.println(j);" so I can tell what j is), I get "It is not in the array" even when it is. Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use the java.util.Arrays utility class. It can convert your array to a list allowing you to use the contains method or it has a binary search allowing you to find the index of your number, or -1 if it is not in the array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class arrays {
    Random random = new Random();

    public void method () {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        int j = random.nextInt(20);

        if( Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, j) != -1 ) {
            System.out.println("It is in the array.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not in the array.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(j)
```

or

```
ArrayUtils.contains( numbers, j )
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your array is sorted, you can use [Arrays.binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) which returns index of the element if it is present in the `array`, otherwise returns `-1`.

```
if(Arrays.binarySearch(numbers,j) != -1){
     system.out.println("It is in the array.");
} else {
     system.out.println("It is not in the array.");
}
```

Just a faster way to search and you also don't need to convert your `array` to `list`.