# Compare String with String[] with boolean?

Tags: java, arrays, string, boolean, return

I want to compare from a void main method where there is a array and a string. so what I want to do is to compare with if name is in the array. return true else return false. But I cant get it to work. It gives me false on both. And I don't know why?

```
public boolean isActor(String name) {

        if(name.equals(actors)) {
            return true;

        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] actors = {"Ulla Skoog", "Suzanne Reuter", "Peter Dalle"} ;
    Dvd d1 = new Dvd(10327, "Yrrol", "Peter Dalle", actors, 88);
    System.out.println("Medverkar Kalle Kula i Lorry: " + d1.isActor("Kalle kula"));
    System.out.println("Medverkar Ulla Skoog i Lorry: " + d1.isActor("Ulla Skoog"));

}
```

Any help would be appreciated !

EDIT: So I tried to do if(Arrays.asList(actors).contains(name)) and yes it worked. Problem is I might now be allowed to do it under a test which can make me losing points and I tried to make a for loop and by that make a equals statement but still getting the same result which is both false.

EDIT2: Also tried to do this

```
public boolean isActor(String name) {
          for(String s: actors){
                if(s.equals(actors))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

but still got the same result of both false

EDIT3:

What I want to do is to make e method which is ( public boolean isActor(String name) { ) and with that I want to make a if-statement which should make a algorithm by saying "If this name is on this array. make it say true. If its not in the array. Say its false." Thats what im trying to do.

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile. My suggestion to atleast make it compile - and we are always there to help. There are lot of java tutorials on the net - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ is the official one from Oracle.

Comment: The question linked above is how you do what you want to do. As to why your code is not working, `equals` does exactly what it says it does, it checks whether 2 things are equal, and a `String` is not equal to an array, regardless of what's actually in this array (just like I'm not equal to the room I'm currently in).

Comment: Oh. So I tried to make a if(Arrays.asList(actors).contains(name)) and yes it worked. but there should be easier way to do it since I dont really know if its allowed to do this under test in school so I tried to make a for loop and then make a if(name.equals(actor) but it gives me the same result which Should work if im right?

Comment: There's presumably something wrong with your for-loop then. [One of the answers in the linked post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12635769/1711796) has a for-loop which you can use as a starting point ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23526351/1711796)'s a simpler version).

Comment: @Dukeling so I did the number 3 and it still gave me the same result. which will be for me public boolean isActor(String name) {
    for(String s: actors){
          if(s.equals(actors))
              return true;
      }
      return false;
  }

Comment: @Thrillofit123 why you don't use `name` to test equalty ?

Comment: @Thrillofit123 What you are doing buddy ? First be clear about what you want to do and den only try for that.

Comment: What I want to do is to make e method which is (  public boolean isActor(String name) { ) and with that I want to make a if-statement which should make a algorithm by saying "If this name is on this array. make it say true. If its not in the array. Say its false." Thats what im trying to do.

Comment: @Thrillofit123 use convexHull answer, it does what you want

Comment: @Hacketo I have done it and it still gave me false on everything. Which I dont understand why. Logical it should work. I might see what could be wrong. I will try with debugg now.

Comment: @Thrillofit123 Well your example of edit2 is not using `name` to do the test so it can't work, you should look the answer more carefuly

Answer (score 2):

You have to test each item in array:

```
public boolean isActor(String name) {

    for (String actor : actors) {
        if (name.equals(actor) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried aswell but it didnt work. got False both of them. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isActor(String name, List<String> actorList) {

    if(actorList.contains(name)) {
        return true;

    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] actors = {"Ulla Skoog", "Suzanne Reuter", "Peter Dalle"} ;   
    List<String> actorList = Arrays.asList ( actors);
    Dvd d1 = new Dvd(10327, "Yrrol", "Peter Dalle", actors, 88);
    System.out.println("Medverkar Kalle Kula i Lorry: " + d1.isActor("Kalle kula",actors));
    System.out.println("Medverkar Ulla Skoog i Lorry: " + d1.isActor("Ulla Skoog",actors));
}
```

Comment: Problem is I cant take the String[] actors up to the method because it is not allowed for me do to it. So is there any other way?

Comment: pass that also to the method

Comment: Sorry to say but I dont think I have to make a add on parameters. I also think im not allowed to add something. So yeah. I should start with  public boolean isActor(String name) { and make a statement take will it true or false by static void main method.