# How to randomly seat groups of passengers in an airline in java? Step-by-Step

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm new to Java and I have this program i'm working on about seating groups of passengers in an airline. ( I would try to make my question simple and easy to understand)

So, I am supposed to seat passengers in an airline in groups. I get the information on how they are being seated by a booking class.

```
public class Bookings {
public Bookings() {
}

public static void main(String[] var0) {
    System.out.println("Do not run this program.");
    System.out.println("Call the method as follows:");
    System.out.println("  String[] bookings = Bookings.getBookings()");
}

    public static String[] getBookings() {
        return new String[]{"38", "2", "Gurganus, Erik", "Gurganus, Fernando", "1", "Cahn, Lance", "1", "Burrough, Jamie", "3", "Riney, Christian", "Marceau, Hillary", "Marceau, Julio", "3", "Gariepy, Noemi", "Gariepy, Louisa", "Gariepy, Nelson", "2", "Mazzoni, Max", "Fiorita, Tyrone", "3", "Ehle, Clinton", "Minnifield, Clinton", "Blinn, Jamie", "2", "Sokolowski, Kurt", "Sokolowski, Sofia", "2", "Secord, Hugh", "McVeigh, Karina", "1", "McMonagle, Christian", "1", "Canchola, Clayton", "2", "Duer, Julio", "Danos, Ted", "3", "Regal, Christian", "Mun, Allan", "Mun, Lakisha", "2", "Noblitt, Karina", "Tussey, Clayton", "1", "Seckman, Jamie", "2", "Folmar, Edwina", "Lokey, Clayton", "2", "Pippen, Javier", "Saba, Earlene", "4", "Tippit, Lorrie", "Tippit, Harriett", "Tippit, Clare", "Tippit, Lance", "3", "Mazurek, Mallory", "Mazurek, Stefan", "Mazurek, Ihor", "2", "Saini, Amie", "Peavler, Darcy"};
    }
   }
```

with this information I created a String array called seats and a bookings array that calls the class to retrieve all the information in it

```
String[] seats = new String[38];
String[] bookings = Bookings.getBookings();
```

The first value indicates the number of seats available on my flight and the remaining values indicates the numbers of groups to be assigned and their names.

## For more clarification, the steps to follow for this procedure is:

> **Your program will seat passengers as follows:**
>   It will create a "seats" array of the appropriate size (given in the first >position of the "bookings" array). **DONE**
>
> It will process the remaining items in the "bookings" array of strings. >For each group of passengers it will attempt to seat
>   them as follows: **DONE**
>
> - First, it will see if there are enough seats remaining on the flight for everyone in the group; if not, it will display an
>     error message and not assign seats to anyone in the group.
> - Secondly, it will go through the "seats" array to determine if a block of empty seats large enough to seat the entire group together
>     is available (for example, if the group size is 3, it will see if
>     there are 3 consecutive empty seats).
>
>   If there is at least one such block of seats anywhere in the array,
>     randomly assign the group to one of these blocks by randomly
>     selecting an element in the "seats" array.
>
>   If that seat is empty, determine if enough successive array elements
>     (seats) are also empty to seat the entire group; if so, seat them
>     there.
>
>   Otherwise, randomly try another seat, repeating until successful.
>
>   If there is no such block, randomly assign each passenger in the
>     group individually to a seat (i.e., the group will be split up). For
>     each passenger, pick random seat numbers until you find an empty
>     seat.

My problem now are these two steps, I wrote this step for solving it down on a sheet of paper but i'm not sure whether or not i'm on the right track. Any contribution/help would be very much appreciated. I can provide more information on the problem if needed.

```
for(int i =0; i<seats.length; i++) {
        if(seats[i] == null) {
            for(int i =0; i<seats.length; i++) {
                if(seats.equals(null) > passengerGroup) {
                    (randomly seat them consecutively);
                } else {
                    (randomly seat them anywhere)
                }
            }
        } else {
            system.out.println( "No seats available");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your if statement on the second line will say  `No seats available` after the first booking. You have to check whether the whole array is full, not just the the specific value. Add the statement specified here to fix that problem:  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: What do you mean with `if(seats.equals(null) > passengerGroup)` in your pseudo-code? It would not compile (and by [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), `anything.equals(null)` is always `false`).

Comment: Whats the problem here? The algorithm/steps are explained very well in the explanation you provided. You just need to translate that to java code.

Comment: I was just trying to understand the questions properly. I'm still trying to get ahold of this question & java properly @MickMnemonic.

Comment: The problem is I can't translate it to java properly. Perhaps, you can help translate it algorithmically? @wazaaaap The question gets even more confusing to me in the first two steps because i'm still learning the language

Comment: In for loops iterator index variable names have to be different.

Comment: @girlCoder, really, you simply need to fire up your IDE and _start coding_. When you run into compilation / run-time problems, you can post a more specific question and will be assisted by the community.

Comment: I have a problem understanding the first two steps especially searching the arrays consecutively, @MickMnemonic

Comment: Any contribution on how to get through would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You could do this: Define two counter variables. Counting `int emptySeats`, you loop through `seats` and simply increment it for each `if(seats[i] == null)`. For `int emptyConsecutiveSeats`, you also need to loop through `seats`, but break out when you find an occupied seat; you can declare `boolean previousSeatEmpty = true;` which you use in the looping condition: `for(int i =0; i<seats.length && previousSeatEmpty; i++)`. Then amend `if(seats[i] == null) {emptyConsecutiveSeats++;}` with `else {previousSeatEmpty = false;}`.

Comment: For the random seat assignment part, you could also declare an `int[] availableSeats` array (or better, a `List` if you can use dynamic data structures) which keeps track of array indices of `seats` which are available (and which you populate while looping). Then you could use `java.util.Random` for selecting a seat from `availableSeats` randomly.

Comment: that's what I used to write the code just that i used a method and I used the math.random function instead since I've only learnt up to that level. Can you use it in the comment section instead? Thanks :) @MickMnemonic

Comment: Yes, `Math.random()` internally uses `java.util.Random` so it's equivalent (but with less functionality). One final note: you will be better off modeling `seats` with a `boolean` array (`boolean[] seats`) because that way the value of `seat[i]` could explicitly indicate whether the seat is occupied (`true`) or available (`false`). If you do it this way, you need to check for `if (!seats[i])` instead of `if(seats[i] == null)` for seat availability within the loop. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break down the problem before writing loops; counters are the easiest way to keep track of availability in this situation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int numSeats = 20;
    int available = numSeats;
    int numGroups = 6;
    
    int groupSizes[] = new int[numGroups];
    
    groupSizes[0] = 2;
    groupSizes[1] = 1;
    groupSizes[2] = 5;
    groupSizes[3] = 3;
    groupSizes[4] = 10;
    groupSizes[5] = 2;
    
    for (int i=0; i < groupSizes.length; i++) {
        
        if (available > groupSizes[i]){
            available -= groupSizes[i];
            System.out.println("Group: " + i + " has been book on!");
        }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("Not enough seats for group: " + i);
        }
        
    }
    System.out.println(available + " Seats remaining");
}
```