# Java Operator To prove Inclusion to an array

Tags: java, arrays

In the following example I am trying to make sure if a clicked button is included inside a certain JButton array. When pressing the button in the screen I just getting the string false which means the while loop evaluates to false.
I think if I am not wrong that this is because **`Arrays.asList(ArrName).contains(element)`** doesent apply to primitive types.
If my guess is true how to solve this issue? If it is not true what is the solution for this ?

```
            JButton[] num;
            c = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(this.num).contains(c));
            while(Arrays.asList(this.num).contains(c)){
                System.out.println("True");
            }
```

Comment: [`ArrayList.contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)? Or were you looking for something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you try to find a string in a JButton array.

Change `c = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();` to `c = (JButton) e.getSource();`