# generate random number and store to array then check of the same new random

Tags: java, random

I generated 1-10 random numbers and stored it in an array. My question is how I'm going to code this first, random three times if 2 or all of them are duplicates then random again three times and if they are different from each other then save to the array. so here's my code:

```
CODE:

int min=1;
int max=10;
int y=0;

Random rand = new Random();

for(int count=0;count<1;count++){
   int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
   arr[count] = randomNum;
}
System.out.println(arr[0]);//for checking
System.out.println(randomNum);//for checking
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: You want to check for duplicates? duplicates followed by each other? Rephrase please

Comment: if (arr[0] != randonNum) is the answer to your question. If you wanted for n values you should have asked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the array contains this random number.

```
Arrays.asList(arr).contains(randomNum)
```

If it doesn't then you add it in the array, otherwise you throw an exception or ignore in depends what your logic is.

Similar question I think: [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkArray(Int[] arr, Int targetValue) {
    for(Int i: arr){
        if(i == targetValue)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a little explanation as to how and why this works?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for :

```
public static int[] generatePureRandomIntegers(int n) {
    final int[] array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = i + 1;
    }
    final Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    for (int i = array.length; i > 1; i--) {
        swap(array, i - 1, random.nextInt(i));
    }
    return array;
}

private static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}
```

create a new array of `int`s and fill it from `1` to `n` then shuffle the array.

for example :

```
int[] randomNumbers = generatePureRandomIntegers(10);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomNumbers)); // [4, 6, 5, 7, 1, 10, 8, 9, 2, 3]
```