# Is there a way to shorten something like this?

Tags: java

In this part of the code, a scanner asks the user to input a number between one and five. I will need to rewrite this for a bunch of variables, so is there any way to make it shorter?

```
if (Q1 != 1 || Q1 != 2 || Q1 != 3 || Q1 !=4 || Q1 != 5) {
    System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
}
```

Instead of typing `Q1 != 1` or 2 or 3 etc, is there a way to write 1-5 or something like that?

Comment: You should try to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: This is always `true`.

Comment: @RC. yes because `1!=2 == true` and `1!=3 == true` ...

Comment: AFAIK there is some kind of "shortcut" 1!=1 is false so..

Comment: @RC. this is _or_, not _and_.

Comment: yeah my bad it's 1:30am here :)

Comment: Q1 must equal one through five, meaning it can't be six or anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(Q1 <1 || Q1 >5) System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number between 1 and 5.")
```

Comment: I'd be completely satisfied with this answer if you left an explanation as to why it works.  I admit it's pretty apparent, but still...

Comment: Since you're checking the values over a range instead of discreet random numbers this should work. The If statement checks the input against the range.

Comment: It was apparent, I do know why it works. I'm just dumb and didn't even think of it.

Answer (score -1):

For the general case, use a set.

Declare a class field, or a local variable:

```
Set<Integer> accepted = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
```

Then:

```
if (!accepted.contains(Q1))
    System.out.println("Error: Please enter a number that is one of: " + accepted);
```

Use `LinkedHashSet` so the printed version has the same order as the declaration.

Comment: It's not that your answer's *wrong*, it's just overkill for this scenario.

Comment: @Makoto Quote "for a general case..."

Answer (score -1):

The above answers are nice for this specific problem, but if you have 5 separate Strings for example, and you want to check if each of them are valid (they aren't null or empty), then you should create a method, to do that.

```
public boolean isValid(String... args) { 
    for (String s : args) {
        if (s == null or s.equals("")) {
            //Something is invalid 
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Everything is valid
    return true;
}
```