# Searching an array using loop

Tags: arrays, search

I have an array of numbers 1 to 10 and I am taking a number from user.

Now I want to check whether that number is present in my array or not so is there any way to search it.
I wanted it to be searched using loop as we to do in C programming

Comment: can you please post the minimal source code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following is the scenario

```
    int numbers[] = { 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

//easiest way if your array is already sorted is to use binarySearch

    if(Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, number_input_by_user) >=0 ){
                 //found in array
            }else{
                   //not found in array
    }
```

If your array is not sorted you can use

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);
```