# Is value in ArrayList<Integer>? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

In Java, I'm trying to know whether an `Integer` is in an `ArrayList<Integer>`.
I tried using [this general solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128728/3399416), which warns that it *doesn't work with arrays of primitives*. That shouldn't be a problem, since `Integer`s aren't primitives (`int`s are).

```
ArrayList<Integer> ary = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ary.add(2);

System.out.println(String.format("%s", Arrays.asList(ary).contains(2)));
```

Returns `false`.
Any reason why?
Any help is appreciated, although the less verbose the better.

Comment: Why do you call `Arrays.asList(ary)`? `ary` was declared as an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `ArrayList<T>` inherited from `List<T>` and thus already had a `contains()` method... This was kind of a trivial question, so I'll leave it up to the community to decide whether to keep it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any reason why it returns `false`?

Simply because `Arrays.asList(ary)` will return a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>` and you try to find if it contains an `Integer` which cannot work.

As remainder here is the Javadoc of `Arrays.asList(ary)`

> `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)` Returns a fixed-size list
>   backed by the specified array.

Here as you provide as argument an `ArrayList<Integer>`, it will return a `List` of what you provided so a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

You need to call [List#contains(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) on your list something like `ary.contains(myInteger)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `asList()` as ArrayList itself a list. Also you don't need `String.format()` to print the result. Just do in this way. This returns `true` :

```
System.out.println(ary.contains(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to coerce your ArrayList to a List when it already is. Arrays.asList takes an array or variable number of arguments and adds all of these to a list. All you need to do is call System.out.println(ary.contains(2));