# Find match element in array

Tags: java

completely new to Java, I am trying to find the matched element from one array into another, cannot seem to understand how to do it. Here is a sample of how the data is and how far I've gotten:

In this code and after printing this line, this is how the data is:

```
ArrayList<String> all_accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
all_accounts.add(acc);
System.out.println("\nArray 1:" + all_accounts);
```

Result Array 1:

```
Array 1:[77737320]
Array 1:[88405378]
Array 1:[00056893]
Array 1:[10709816]

ArrayList<String> cancel_accounts = new ArrayList<String>();
cancel_accounts.add(cancel_acc);
System.out.println("\nArray 2:" + cancel_accounts);
```

Results from Array 2:

```
Array 2:[77737320]
Array 2:[]
Array 2:[]
Array 2:[]
```

Stack here, I still cant understand why it doesn't match:

```
     String found = null;
     for (String account: all_accounts) {

       for (String canceled: cancel_accounts) {
          System.out.println(canceled);
          found = canceled;
        }
     System.out.println(found);
     if(account.equals(found) ) {
              System.out.println(account);
         }

    }
```

I need to find the matched element, 77737320 in this case.
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Comment: @PeterPerháč The question is quite different, here the OP asks for array that contains more then one element not only one.

Comment: @user6904265 i insist that this question has definitely been answered here and OP can figure out how to do it looking at the other question i linked. this is "do my homework for me" kind of question and shouldn't be here

Answer (score 3):

+1 for answer from user6904265

However, You need not create a new HashSet. You can use ArrayList.retainAll(). If you want to maintain the all_accounts list, create a new clone and use that instead.

Comment: I updated my answer with your hint. But if you don't want duplicate values (if input array contains any) in the final array you should use `Set`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement this as intersection between sets:

```
Set<String> set_all_account = new HashSet<String>(all_accounts);
Set<String> set_cancel_accounts = new HashSet<String>(cancel_accounts);
set_all_account.retainAll(set_cancel_accounts);
set_all_account.forEach(x -> System.out.println("Element matched: "+x));
```

Or as said by kartiks in his comment you could call the `retainAll` method directly on the `all_accounts` array:

```
all_accounts.retainAll(cancel_accounts);
all_accounts.forEach(x -> System.out.println("matched element: "+x));
```

Pay attention with this solution because in this case `retainAll` applies directly on the ArrayList and modifies it (as you can see the final result is in the `all_accounts` array). Moreover duplicate elements remain in the result array.

Last implementation (if you want compute intersection and print the result all in one line, also this version keeps duplicate elements):

```
all_accounts.stream().filter(x -> cancel_accounts.contains(x)).forEach(x -> System.out.println("matched element: "+x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `equals` check to your for - loops (will work even without `List#contains` method)

```
for(String account: all_accounts) {
    System.out.println(account);

   for(String canceled: cancel_accounts){
     System.out.println(canceled);

     if(account.equals(cancelled)){
         //you've found first intersection, cancelled exists in both
         System.out.println(canceled + " is the same as " + account); 

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying like this , I still don't understand why it doesn't  match:

      String found = null;
      for (String account: all_accounts) {
      
  for (String canceled: cancel_accounts) {
    System.out.println(canceled);
    found = canceled;
  }
   System.out.println(found);
   if(account.equals(found) ) {
                  System.out.println(account);
          }
  
       }

Comment: Try it EXACTLY as the answer above - and watch where you put curly brackets. What you have pasted in the above comment has a serious logic mistake.

Comment: I think the issue is that all the data is coming one element at a time, as in data sample above, thats why I can not find the match.

Comment: did you run the code above? If there are 2 same strings in those 2 arrays, code above will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the one list and search the second list for each element in first.

```
for (String account: all_accounts) {
    if (cancel_accounts.contains(account) {
        // Match found - do something....
        System.out.println(account);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, if the value is of `primitive` type, `List#contains` method won't work. Should work with a `String` though.