# is there any way to put for loop inside if condition statement as a short cut?

Tags: java, syntax

for example I want to do something like this:

```
package tst;

public class forInif {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        if (for(int i : a) {i == 5;}) {/**/}
    }
}
```

I know normally I should make a boolean value of this situation by my own, but just in case, is there anyway to do something like that rather than make a boolean value somewhere else?

Comment: I hope there is no way to do that. Extract the loop to separate method and do if(myLoopedMethodReturnedTrue()){}

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: There is a one-liner in Java 8 using streams, but other than this you are better off just writing a loop to iterate over the `int[]` array yourself.

Comment: What boolean value you expect from a "loop"? How do you imagine it? what it should show? Just use what you already wrote, but other way around: `for(int i : a) {if (i == 5) {/**/ break;}} `

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There's a one-liner for all Java versions (1.2+), assuming array is sorted like it is in the question: `if (Arrays.binarySearch(a, 5) >= 0) {/**/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8+, you can use [`IntStream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-):

```
if (IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(i -> i == 5)) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly no: the condition check in a Java `if` needs to be a `boolean` type. But you *could* build a function:

```
public class forInif {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
        if (foo(a)) {/**/}
    }
}
```

where `foo` is a function returning a `boolean` that takes an `int[]` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a for loop return a boolean value. However, streams sound like a good way to do this in one or two lines:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int fives = Arrays.stream(a).filter(e -> e == 5).count();
if (fives > 0) {
    //replace this with whatever you want to do when a five is found
    System.out.println("One or more fives exists in the array");
}
```

Comment: Replacing `count()` with `findAny()` would be better: `if (Arrays.stream(a).filter(e -> e == 5).findAny()) {/**/}`