# Search array list for substring

Tags: java

Let say I have an array list with names and the names are stored like this...

```
    John(2), 
    Bob(anytext), 
    Rick
```

I'm trying to iterate over my array list and check for "(" basically and just take the rest of the string behind it and return that as a string, and null if nothing there. I've seen methods to do similar things but I can't seem to find something to just return the rest of the string if it finds the "("

Comment: How about a Matcher, or using indexOf and substring?

Comment: your way of representing a name value is rather weird.

Comment: Where's the code you've tried?

Comment: I've never seen Matcher before. Let me try that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
  String s = list.get(i);
  int x = s.indexOf('(');
  if(x==-1) break;
  return s.substring(x+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the strings you want to check to a method that does something like this:

```
        if(str.contains("(")){
           return str.substring(str.indexOf("("));
        }else{
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 version

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("John(2)", "Bob(anytext)", "Rick");
String result = list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.contains("("))
        .findFirst()
        .map(x -> x.substring(x.indexOf("(")))
        .orElse(null);
```