# how to check which location in an array a value belongs to (java)?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, location

the title is a little non-descriptive so i'll give background here.

I am making a snakes and ladders game, and the players location is stored in a variable, playerLocation.

I have an array of spots i would like to check, known as "spotLocations".

I check if the players location is in the spot using

```
if (Arrays.asList(spotLocations).contains(playerLocation))
```

Once this is done, i would like to check which slot in the array that value is found.
Code is written in java using eclipse.

Comment: You could also look at this thread for more information:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Comment: Why don't you just search the array with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int pos = Arrays.asList(spotLocations).indexOf(playerLocation)
```