# How can I check number present or not in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, oop

I have to display that given number present in array or not.
**For example:**

```
int[] number1 = {2,3,6,14,23,8,23,19};   
int[] numbers2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};
```

Now I have to check whether number1 array element present in number2 array or not if yes then print present number.
So how can I achieve this in Java?

My code:

```
int[] number1 = {2,3,6,14,23,8,23,19};   
    int[] numbers2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

for(int i=0; i<number2.length;i++){
    for(int j =0; j<number1.length:j++){
        if(number2[i]==number1[j]){
            System.out.println("present number is:"+number1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any Try?.......

Comment: Yes, I will try, but when I execute the program, it will check only the first value of number1 array.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Change i --> j  at System.out.println("present number is:"+number1[j]);

Comment: Thanks @gifpif It works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested for loop will help you to achieve that, basically for each number in `number1`, you need to traverse `numbers2` to see if the value is present.

```
for(int i: number1) {
        for(int j: numbers2) {
            if(i == j) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break; //exit the inner loop if the number is present
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea

1. Iterate through the first array using a for loop.
2. Use an inner for loop to iterate through the elements of second array and keep comparing the value.
3. If the value is found, print it and break out of inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

Change i --> j at `System.out.println("present number is:"+number1[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and clean when using Java 8.

```
int[] number1 = {2,3,6,14,23,8,55,23,19};
int[] numbers2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30};

Arrays.stream(numbers2)
        .filter(num -> Arrays.stream(number1).anyMatch(e -> e == num))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```