# Checking if number is a member of a matrix

Tags: java, matlab, matrix

Matlab has this function called `ismember(n,P)` that allows us to check if the number `n` is in the matrix `P`. If `n` is in `P` it returns 1, otherwise 0. My question is, is there anything similar in Java that would allow me to check the above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does java have matices?

Comment: Is there a reason why writing a simple loop and comparing each element is not good enough? You should show what you've tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate?: [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1128723/52738)

Comment: @tkausl Correct me if I am wrong but is this not a matrix in Java? `int[][] scores = {{1,2,3},{6,7,8},{2,0,5}};`

Comment: @Justin Thanks, I wrote a loop as you suggested and it worked but just wanted to see if there was an even quicker way of checking