# How do I check if INPUT from a user matches an item in an array.(Like a login)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a login type validation, In the long run, I need to tokenize items from a .txt file, but for now, I just have the items inside of an array.

**I'm trying to validate if the item is contained within the array**(and what is the index of that item)

```
package pkgMTA;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;  

public class pkgMTA {
public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean validations = false;    
String[] gArray = new String[5];
gArray[0] = "AAA";
gArray[1] = "BBB";
gArray[2] = "CCC";
gArray[3] = "DDD";
gArray[4] = "EEE";


String input;
input = scan.nextLine();

for( int i = 0; i < gArray.length; i++)
{
  if( gArray[i].equals(input)){
    validations = true;
}
  else{
  validations = false;
 }
 }

if (validations){

System.out.println("nice");
}
else {
System.out.println("error");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
else {
    validations = false:
}
```

part. Since you don't want to set the validations variable to false if the input doesn't match **one** of the elements of your list. However you do want it to be true if there's at least one match.

I also strongly advise using proper indentation.

The corrected code (properly formatted):

```
package pkgMTA;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class pkgMTA {
    public static void main(String[] Args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);   
        boolean validations = false;
        String[] gArray = new String[5];
        gArray[0] = "AAA";
        gArray[1] = "BBB";
        gArray[2] = "CCC";
        gArray[3] = "DDD";
        gArray[4] = "EEE";

        String input;
        input = scan.nextLine();
        for( int i = 0; i < gArray.length; i++) {
            if( gArray[i].equals(input)) {
                validations = true;
            }
        }
        if (validations) {
            System.out.println("nice");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or break the loop after you find one:

```
if( gArray[i].equals(input)){
validations = true;
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning to implement this algorithm properly is important, but for future reference: Java has built-in functionality for this purpose:

1. For simple, one-time use you can just write
   `boolean validation=java.utils.Arrays.asList(gArray).contains(input);`
2. For repeated checks of a large number of items you could use a [`HashSet<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which is a bit more complicated to fill, but its `contains(input)` call is faster