# java| how to make one variable for all digits (0-9)

Tags: java

i'm working on my project in java, in my project i need to get input from some stream an to parse text and make it to generic  char-by-char  to some other types, one of them is "ValueNumber".

for that I'm using switch case

Now,because Number can start with ' - ' I need to check if the current char is a Digit between 0 to 9 or ' - ' or something else.

My question is how can I make some variable that will hold all the 10th digits by one variable ?

Answer (score 0):

String will hold it, or StringBuilder for better performance and
then you can parse the string and see if it matches the regex:

```
return str.matches("[-]?[0-9]+");
```

if true, it is digit with or without negation sign, if false, it is not a digit you described. The digit can be as long as String allows.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're imagining something like:

```
switch(aChar) {
   case '+':
       handlePlus();
       break;
   case ' ':
       handleSpace();
       break;
   case anyOf("-01234567890");
       handlePartOfNumber(aChar);
       break;
}
```

Unfortunately in Java, `switch` is not this sophisticated. `switch` deals with exact matches only.

You will need to use a series of `if/else` blocks instead:

```
if(aChar == '+') {
      handlePlus();
} else if(aChar == ' ') {
    handleSpace();
} else if(isMinusOrDigit(aChar)) {
    handlePartOfNumber(aChar);
}
```

Now, how do we implement `isMinusOrDigit(char c)`?

You've asked about "some variable that holds all the digits". Maybe you mean an array, or a `List` or a `Set`. I'll choose `Set` because it's the purest "bag of items, you don't care the order".

```
private static Set<Character> MINUS_AND_DIGITS = minusAndDigits();

private static Set<Character> minusAndDigits() {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(char c = '0'; c<='9'; c++) {
        set.add(c);
    }
    set.add('-');
}

private static boolean isMinusOrDigit(char c) {
    return MINUS_AND_DIGITS.contains(c);
}
```

You could also use

- a `List<Character>` (again `.contains(c)`)
- an array -- `char[]` (see [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value))
- or even a `String` -- `return "0123456789-".indexOf(c) != -1;`

But in this case, you don't need a "multi value variable" to work out whether a character is a minus or a digit - because the number characters are next to each other in ASCII:

```
private static boolean isMinusOrDigit(char c) {
    return c == '-' || ( c >= 0 && c<=9 ); 
}
```

Comment: You can't -- as explained in the answer. Use a chain of if/else statements instead.