# Saving memory and CPU in java loops

Tags: java, loops, memory, optimization, cpu

this (obvious) code i've writen works well, but for testing purposes, i should make it work for a "one million" sized array in a reasonable time by saving CPU Cycles and saving as much memory as i can.
any suggestions please?
!!! the array is arranged in ascending order !!!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class A {
static boolean exists(int[] ints, int k) {
    for(int integer : ints){
        if(integer == k){
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: binary search if you shoud use an array, otherwise you can use hash

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-can-i-test-if-an-array-contains-a-certain-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your array is in ascending order, one thing you could do (i think) is to make a binary search instead of a linear search.

Comment: `int index = Arrays.binarySearch(new int[] {1,2,4}, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Set<Integer>` that relies on hashing rather than an array where you iterate sequentially.

```
static boolean exists(Set<Integer> ints, int k) {
     return ints.contains(k);
}
```

You could convert the array to a `Set` and pass it to the method as many times as required :

```
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
boolean isExist = exists(set, 15);
 ...
isExist = exists(set, 5005);
 ...
isExist = exists(set, 355);
```