# Stuck on making an if statement for my game

Tags: java

Trying to make an if statement for a game where I give the user a scrambled word and they have to input a word made up of those scrambled letters. I have hardcoded three answers they can use. I'm stuck on trying to make an IF else statement to tell the user if they got the answer correct or to try again.

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Scramble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] wordbank = new String [10];
        int answer; 
        wordbank[0] = "GALEE";
        wordbank[1] = "OLWBE"; 
        wordbank[2] = "RHCIA"; 
        wordbank[3] = "RWSIT"; 
        wordbank[4] = "NTARI"; 
        wordbank[5] = "ETLBA"; 
        wordbank[6] = "TIRSH"; 
        wordbank[7] = "TLUFE"; 
        wordbank[8] = "MIGEIN"; 
        wordbank[9] = "RAEHT"; 
        String[] GALEE = {"Eagle", "Gale", "Leg"};
        String[] OLWBE = {"Elbow", "Below", "Lobe"}; 
        String[] RHCIA = {"Chair", "Hair", "Air"}; 
        String[] RWSIT = {"Wrist", "Wit", "It"}; 
        String[] NTARI = {"Train", "Rant", "Art"}; 
        String[] ETBLA = {"Table", "Late", "Bet"}; 
        String[] TIRSH = {"Shirt", "Sir", "Sh"}; 
        String[] TLUFE = {"Flute", "Felt", "let"}; 
        String[] MIGEIN = {"Gemini", "Mini", "Gem"}; 
        String[] RAEHT = {"Heart", "Hate", "Ear"}; 

        System.out.println("Create a five letter word out of " + wordbank[0] + ".");
        answer = s.nextInt();
        if (answer) { 

        }
```

Comment: Note that `nextInt()` reads an `int` value, you probably want to read a `String` (i.e `next()`) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: You want to check if the value (given by the player) is in the array (answers you hard coded). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment by Arnaud, you should probably use `next()`, at least check that the value of `answer` is really the user input.

Once this is out of the way, you will want to check that `answer` is one of the three acceptable solutions.

You can use this in java 8:

```
boolean resultOk = Arrays.asList(GALEE).contains(answer);
if (resultOK) {
    // do something
}
```

This will check that `answer` belongs to your `GALEE` array (so it has to be equal to either `eagle`, `gale` or `leg`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the user types the word, you need to read it with `next()` instead of `nextInt()`.

The `if` statement reads a boolean, that boolean in this case should come from a comparison (for example, `equals` as a simple solution).

```
if(answer.equals("Eagle")){
  //do something
}
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more info

Or, for a better solution you should try to check in only one step if the answer given by the user matches some element of the array

```
if(Arrays.asList(GALEE).contains(answer)){
  //do something
}
```

For this you can check [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: I have to note that this will get real messy real fast. What if the wordbank is 100 words?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through `GALEE` to see if what they have entered is equal to one of the words in `GALEE`.
This is what your code should look like:

```
String answer = scanner.nextLine();
boolean matches = false;

for(String combination: GALEE){
    if(answer.equals(combination)){
        matches = true;
        break
    }
}
if(matches){
    System.out.println("You got it correct!");
} else{
    System.out.println("You got it wrong!");
}
```

I'd also like to note that you asked them to

> Create a five letter word

but some of the words in `GALEE` are less than 5 letters long.