# How to get the smallest value of an array, starting somewhere?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] a = {2,7,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int merker = a[0];
        int i =4;
        int n = a.length;
        while(i<n){
            if(a[i] < merker)
                merker = a[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.print(merker);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the while loop does not start at the 5th number of the array as i made `int i = 4;`.

Comment: Why do you think your loop does not start at the 5th element?

Comment: Since the loop looks for the smallest value, and the smallest value is in `a[0]`, and you initialize `merker` with that smallest value, it doesn't matter where in the loop you start, the result will always be `2`. So how do you even "know" it does not start at the 5th number? --- Did you perhaps intend to initialize `merker` with `a[i]` instead of `a[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process  :

- your `merker` values `2`,
- you look for a value smaller than it, starting at the 5th value,
- there is no smaller value,
- result is `2`

---

To **get the smallest value**, starting at 5th value, uou need to init `merker` at a high value like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i refactor a bit to use a for loop, it's easier to understand :

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;;
int startindice = 4;            >> a[4] is 5th value : {2,7,3,4,>>5<<,6,7,8}
for(int i = startindice; i < a.length; i++)
    if(a[i] < min)
        min = a[i];
```

---

To check wether a value is present or not, with a simple for loop

```
boolean isPresent(int[]array, int value){
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        if(a[i] == value)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

For Java 8 ways : [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java#answers)

Comment: why would integer.Max_value; make it start at the 5th?

Comment: @LaffaYett the `i=4` for 5th value

Comment: i tryed to do a loop now where i can just give out a boolean which responses "true" if i have a specific number in my array.

Comment: @LaffaYett You should learn more Java, before trying to thses kind of stuff, you're missing competences ;) I've edit

Answer (score 0):

It does. To verify you can add a println statement:

```
$ cat Main.java
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] a = {2,7,3,4,5,6,7,8};
        int merker = a[0];
        int i =4;
        int n = a.length;
        while(i<n){
            System.out.println("Is " + a[i] + " < " + merker + "? "+ (a[i] < merker) );
            if(a[i] < merker)
                merker = a[i];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.print("merker = " + merker);
    }
}

$ java Main
Is 5 < 2? false
Is 6 < 2? false
Is 7 < 2? false
Is 8 < 2? false
merker = 2⏎
```

Comment: im somehow thought it will start at 4, but thats stupid since the merker is set at the 0 position.

Comment: the maker is assigned the first value (not the position) which is specified by `a[0]` yes