# What do I need here in my code to check if an element in an array is the same with the previous

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a program to compare if an element in an array has the same value, if there is an element in the array that are the same, it prints "Yes", otherwise "No".

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistinctNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.in"));
        int sizeN = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] arrayA = new int[sizeN];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayA.length; j++) {
                arrayA[j] = scanner.nextInt();
                if (arrayA[0] == arrayA[i++]) {
                    System.out.println("Yes");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should say where your problem is. With just a glance it seems like you're only checking if the element arrayA[0] is already in, but not if arrayA[1] == arrayA[2] etc.    EDIT: and you're are increasing i inside the j for loop this code looks really flawed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: @Nordiii do I need to add 'else if'? When I try running the code for output it is printing "Yes" "No" "No" "No"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Edited]** *(see below)*

Do you mean something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.in"));
    int sizeN = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] arrayA = new int[sizeN];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; i++) {
        arrayA[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arrayA[i] == arrayA[j]) {
                System.out.println("Yes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please give us an expected input with an expected output?
You want a simple Yes or No as output or a series of Yes or Nos as an output?

**[Edit]**

If you are trying to check whether there are 2 or more numbers in the array with the same value this might work for you *(however it's not optimal)*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("numbers.in"));
    int sizeN = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] arrayA = new int[sizeN];
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; !found && i < sizeN; i++) {
        arrayA[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; !found && j < i; j++) {
            if (arrayA[i] == arrayA[j]) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: for example when the array elements are say {1, 2, 1, 3} it will simply print "Yes". and if there are no elements of some value, like {5, 4, 1, 2, 3}. "No" will be printed instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wants to do :

```
        if (arrayA[i] == arrayA[j]) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

if any elements of array same, it will be 'Yes'