# Can i add mutiple condition with one starting check?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to do compare it but I have this query can I compare every condition with one go? Like

```
if(exp.charAt(i)=='+','-','/','*')
```

I know I have to do something like this which is correct but i'm trying to find a short way to to this.
`if(exp.charAt(i)=='+',exp.charAt(i)=='-',exp.charAt(i)=='/',exp.charAt(i)=='*'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the characters into a string, and check if the string contains the specific character in your array:

```
String matchingCharacters="+-/*";
if (matchingCharacters.contains(exp.charAt(i)))
    ....
```