# Find String in Array in Java

Tags: java

Why do I get nothing when run the code?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String fname = sc.nextLine();
    String[] farray = new String[]{"Chen", "Chang"};

    if(Arrays.asList(farray).contains(farray)){
        System.out.println("Exits");
    }
```

Is there a logical error I made?

Comment: farray doesn't has itself in its elements, so yes it's a logical error.

Comment: Try looking for `"Chen"` or `"Chang"` in the array, you will get `"Exits"` printed.

Comment: I think that you used `contains(farray)` instead  `contains(fname)` which is the value you get from the scanner

Comment: Yeah my bad contains(fname) is right. Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, you used `farray` instead `fname`

```
if(Arrays.asList(farray).contains(fname)) {
    System.out.println("Exits");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression will return `false` as it `farray` does not have itself in this. It is that simple as that. So nothing got printed.

```
Arrays.asList(farray).contains(farray) // false
```

You can look for element in array. like

```
Arrays.asList(farray).contains("Chang") // return true
```