# Checking if a value is in an array

Tags: java, arrays, input

I was curious how to check whether a value is in an array in Java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] choices = {"choiceA", "choiceB", "choiceC"};

String userChoice = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Let's say we wanted to check if whatever value the user inputs into `userChoice` is in the `choices array`, how could I do that?

Comment: iterate over the elements and use equals, or turn it into a List, and use the contains method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: Create List<String> or Set<String> and use contains() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you do

```java
boolean choicesContainUserChoice = Arrays.asList(choices).contains(userChoice);
```

or if you care about performance a lot

```java
boolean choicesContainUserChoice = false;
for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++ ) {
    if (Objects.equals(choices[i], userChoice) {
         choicesContainUserChoice = true;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If performance matters add `break` after `choicesContainUserChoice = true`

Comment: Yes, I forgot that. Edited my answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

1. Linear search

```
      boolean test = false;
        for (int element : arr) {
            if (element == toCheckValue) {
                test = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

2. Binary search

```
        int res = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, toCheckValue);
        boolean test = res > 0 ? true : false;
```

3. Using List.contains() method

```
         boolean test
            = Arrays.asList(arr)
                  .contains(toCheckValue);
```

4. Using stream.anyMatch() method

```
         boolean test
            = IntStream.of(arr)
                  .anyMatch(x -> x == toCheckValue);
```

5. Using Arrays.stream() method

```
         boolean test
            = IntStream.of(arr)
                  .anyMatch(x -> x == toCheckValue);
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-a-value-is-present-in-an-array-in-java/

Comment: Array in question is an array of strings and you use == in your example. It would not work.