# membership test to find if a number is present in array

Tags: java, arrays, integer, membership

given an array of int is there a way to do membership test to see if a particular number is present in the int array. the question was to do find missing number between 1-10 given by user.
eg [1,2,3,4,5]
if 1 is in array it should give true. I cant seem to post my code here.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class Q1 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter numbers of element: "); 
    int size = scan.nextInt(); 
    int arry[]=new int[size]; 
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){ 
      System.out.println("Enter any number betweent 1-10:"); 
      int element = scan.nextInt(); 
      arry[i] = element; 
    } 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arry)); 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arry).contains(1)); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: why can't you post your code? code is just flat text, just like the flat text you already posted.

Comment: no it didnot answer my question as even if the value was in array it shows false

Comment: i could not post my code as it showed some red dot error even when syntax was correct

Comment: Ngawang, if it does, your value is not in the array.

Comment: i printed the array and then did membership test. the number was in array but it still showed error. are there other method to see if int array contains a particular value?

Comment: @Ngawang show the code you've done. the only reason why that solution shouldn't work, is because you use a datatype that didn't implement equals

Comment: try with Integer instead of int.

Comment: try it in which side of the code? sorry i am just a starter in java.

Comment: instead of int arry, have an Integer[] arry, and arry[i] = new Integer(i); and contains(new Integer(1));

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that `Arrays.asList` will create `List<int[]>` NOT the implied `List<Integer>`, therefore method `.contains(1)` is always `false`.

Simple method should be implemented to check the membership:

```
static boolean isInArray(int n, int ... arr) {
    for (int x : arr) {
        if (x == n) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using Stream API:

```
static boolean isInArray(int n, int ... arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).anyMatch(x -> x == n);
}
```

---

Or the input array should be declared as `Integer[] arry`, then `Arrays.asList` provides appropriate `List<Integer>`, and method `contains(1)` is applicable to such list.

Answer (score 0):

Try streams. I don't think aslist().contains() supports primitives like int. This works though:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Main {  
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9};
    int find_1 = 4;
    int find_2 = 6;
    boolean find_num1 = IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(x -> x == find_1);
    boolean find_num2 = IntStream.of(a).anyMatch(x -> x == find_2);
    System.out.println("First num in array? " + find_num1);
    System.out.println("Second num in array? " + find_num2);
    } 
}
```