# Check if user input is equal to string array

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to check if user input is equal to the array, if not toast error message when pressing a button. I am not sure if I should check input outside the button and then use an if `!equals` inside button to toast the message. Here is my attempt

I have this array in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="people">
        <item>JHON</item>
        <item>MARIE</item>
        <item>ALBERT</item>
        <item>ALEX</item>
    </string-array>
```

Activity.java:

```
String[] peopleArr =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.people);
EditText userinput=findViewById(R.id.editTextUserinput);

Button find = findViewById(R.id.findBtn);
        find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= peopleArr.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (!userinput.getText().toString().equals(peopleArr[i])) {
                        
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
}
```

This is wrong because it is toasting invalid user 4 times when the button is pressed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java

Comment: There might be several problems. I think most of them will be associated what did you entered in the EditText. "JHON" is not equal to "JOHN" and not even "JHON " or " JHON". 

Otherwise you can use the Activity fields even in listeners.

Answer (score 0):

this code check user, if can finde user will Toast: **Valid User** otherwise will Toast: **Invalid User**

```
 String[] peopleArr =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.people);
EditText userinput=findViewById(R.id.editTextUserinput);

Button find = findViewById(R.id.findBtn);
    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Boolean userIsFounded = false;
        for (int i = 0; i <= peopleArr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (userinput.getText().toString().equals(peopleArr[i])) {
                userIsFounded = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        String message  =  (userIsFounded)? "Valid User":"InValid User";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: what about doing nothing if valid user? like do not print any message

Comment: Replace  if(!userIsFounded){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "InvalidUser", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  by last two line