# using one dimension array, how to identify if duplicated or not

Tags: java, arrays, search, duplicates

allows me to enter the Id numbers without fear of duplication. my program should be able to display the list of ID numbers at the end

Comment: When you get a new value from the scanner, you need to check that it's not already added. How would YOU do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to use a `HashSet`, which is built-in to Java. This is a datastructure which you can insert elements into, and also check if a certain element exists in constant time. Thus, when you read in an element, first check if the set contains said element; if so, skip it, otherwise, put it in your list of IDs and also insert it into your HashSet. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: can you complete the code plss? im sorry