# i need help figuring out how to use contain properly

Tags: java, arrays, methods

hello i wanted to know why contain is not working and how to make it work. my Goal is to be able to print out false if it has 2 or 3. i am not sure if i am doing it correctly or if i'm on the right track.

```java
public class Assignment7 {
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] array0 = {3, 5, 6};
      System.out.println("Your implementation of no23 method printed out: " + no23(array0) );
   }
   
   public static void no23(boolean array0){
      int number = 2;
      int numberB = 3;
      int theNumbers = number & numberB;
            
      boolean statemnt = array0.contains(theNumbers);
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is the parameter to `no23` a `boolean`? Should be `void no23(int [] array0)`

Comment: @Johnny Mopp i was trying multiple strings and i thought that boolean would work

Comment: `no23` print return nothing .. why you want to print out in `main` method ?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp sorry i meant variables i thought that strings were variables and got confused

Comment: I think you intended `boolean` to be the return type, instead of `void`.  What you're passing to that method if of type `int[]`, not `boolean`.  I also wonder whether you meant `theNumbers` to be an array as well - did you intend to check if all the numbers are present, rather than doing bitwise arithmetic with them up front?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems.

## Arrays have no `contains` method

> array0.contains(theNumbers)

You cannot call `contains` on an array. Arrays have no such method.

There are [several ways to search an array](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20search%20array%20java&t=osx&ia=web) in Java. If your array is sorted, use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int%5B%5D,int)).

## Ampersand (`&`) flips bits

Your use of `&` is not doing what you think. That operator manipulates bits. See [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java//nutsandbolts/op3.html) by Oracle.com, free of cost.

What you meant to do was create a collection of `int` values. To do that use an array or use a `Collection` object such as [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) or `Set`. See [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) by Oracle to learn about the [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

## Solution

Use a pair of vertical bars for a logical OR operator. Returns *true* if either or both conditions are true. See [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) by Oracle.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 5, 6 } ;
int x = 2 ;
int y = 3 ;
boolean arrayContainsEitherNumber = 
    ( Arrays.binarySearch( arr , x ) < 0 ) 
    ||
    ( Arrays.binarySearch( arr , y ) < 0 )
;
```

Get fancy with streams.

```java
int[] arr = { 3 , 5 , 6 };
boolean hit =
        Arrays
                .stream( arr )                            // Returns an `IntStream`, a series of each `int` value in the array.
                .filter( i -> ( i == 2 ) || ( i == 3 ) )  // Skips any elements not meeting our criteria.
                .findAny()                                // Halts the stream when first element reaches this point.
                .isPresent();                             // Returns true if the payload of this optional exists, false if no payload.
System.out.println( "hit = " + hit );
```

> hit = true

## Declare a return type

As [commented by Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021172/i-need-help-figuring-out-how-to-use-contain-properly/74021389#comment130696976_74021172), your method neglected to return the result to the calling code.

Change the `void`:

```
public static void no23( boolean array0 ) { … }
```

… to `boolean` and return your result:

```
public static boolean no23( boolean array0 ) { 
    … 
    return statemnt ; 
}
```

---

You may detect a theme in this Answer: Study [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) by Oracle before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well, but `theNumbers` is always equal to `00000010 & 00000011 = 00000010 = 2`.

`&` operator is not the same as the `&&` operator. The first one takes two numbers in binary form, and performs an AND operation like shown above.

2 in binary = 00000010

3 in binary = 00000011

`2 & 3 is 00000010 & 00000011 which is 00000010`

The second takes two booleans, and returns true if both are true, else returns false.

Effectively, your function is just checking if your array contains the number 2. If you want to check if there is either the number one (1) or the number two (2), you need to do :

```
public static void no23(int[] array0){ // Also, should be an array      
    boolean containsTwoOrThree = array0.contains(2) || array0.contains(3);
    System.out.println(containsTwoOrThree); // Will print either true or false
    if(containsTwoOrThree) System.out.println("Contains two or three");
    else System.out.println("Doesn't contain");
    // Simple java arrays do not have a "contain" method.
    // Either use Java Lists, or use a for loop to check for values in.
}
```

EDIT: Arrays in java don't have a contains function. Check this answer:
[How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: thanks you for i thought that & was the same for && but contain stills says that i need to rename it

Comment: What is your error message ?