# Check If List of Objects Contains Empty or Null Item Value

Tags: java

I have List of object returned from a native query. This list has String, Integer and Date. The variable looks like this:

`Object[] result = (Object[])query.getSingleResult();`

I need to check whether the list contains null or empty value. ObjectUtils from **org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils** worked effortlessly but if I were to do this without the library, how to achieve same result?

Comment: Why don't you checkout the code of ObjectUtils?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write "The list contains empty values"; nonethtless you can check null values with a loop statement: `for (Object obj : result) if (obj == null) return true; return false;`

Comment: @0009laH empty value for String item. Say the list value {"", 123} expected result is **true** which means the list contains empty value.

Comment: OK I understand :) In this case you can adapt the previous loop by checking `obj instanceof String and obj == ""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine whether an array contains a particular value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128723/how-do-i-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-particular-value-in-java)

Comment: @0009laH  `obj.equals("")` would be more appropriate in Java.

Comment: You're right @SimonMartinelli! I only checked on the imported class which doesn't show the code clearly., gonna check the  Github.

Answer (score 0):

There is no canonical definition of 'empty value' for either Integer or Date.

You just program what you mean, and 'empty' is not a valid answer to the question 'what do you mean'.

For example: "Empty strings, the 0 integer, and sentinel instant value with epochmillis 0 (`Date` is a lie. It does not represent dates; it represents instants, and badly at that; use `java.time.Instant` instead normally)".

Then, you just.. program that:

```
for (Object obj : result) {
  if (obj == null) return false;
  if (obj instanceof Date) {
    if (((Date) obj).getTime() == 0) return false;
  } else if (obj instanceof String) {
    if (((String) obj).isEmpty()) return false;
  } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
    if (((Integer) obj).intValue() == 0) return false;
  } else throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected type: " + obj.getClass());

  return true;
}
```

It's an `if` for every type *because* there is no such thing as `CouldBeEmpty` as an interface that all these types implement. Said differently, "an empty Date" isn't a thing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I tried it with a mock array, but I don't know if it is exactly the same as yours:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          Object result[] = new Object[5];

        result[0] = 1;
        result[1] = "";
        result[3] = 5;
        result[4] = LocalDate.now();
        result[5] = "string";

        boolean listcontainsnullorempty = false;
        for(var obj: result){
            if(obj == null || obj.equals("")){
                listcontainsnullorempty = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listcontainsnullorempty);
    }
```

depending on your list, you might need to add || obj.isEmpty() in the if-clause.